# Can I use acrylic caulk around the bath?

Tags: bathtub

used acrylic caulk in my kitchen on backsplash and love, love it.  you just can't stain it.  want to use it around the bath instead of this rubbery stuff I had.  am i being wrong headed..?

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't be a problem. Keep in mind that unlike silicone, acrylic/latex caulk can (but doesn't always) dry out and crack over time, defeating its waterproofing capabilities, but it's definitely easier to apply and remove/replace.

Most "Kitchen and Bath" caulks are pure silicone, but many people simply use all-purpose siliconized latex caulk like this one:
[image]